# Polarion EventtriggerConfiguration

Tags: javascript, polarion

I have a questen in relation to scripts in Polarion.
I want to develop some scripts to automate a few functions in Polarion. I downloaded a offline version of Polarion to have a seperated test area. Then I included a few Projects from the "online" Polarion server.
Unfortunately I had to find out that the scripts with the EventTriggerConfiguration are no longer called offline(No logs are created). I dont understand why these trigger is not working offline.

```
    <EventTriggerConfiguration> 
    <WorkItem> 
        <type id="task"> 
            <event trigger="post-save"> 
                <script> 
                    <scriptName>project:scripts:createReviewWIPostSavenew.js</scriptName> 
                    <scriptEngine>js</scriptEngine> 
                </script> 
            </event> 
        </type> 
    </WorkItem>  
    <WorkItem> 
        <type id="task"> 
            <event trigger="pre-save"> 
                <script> 
                    <scriptName>project:scripts:createTaskWIPreSavenew.js</scriptName> 
                    <scriptEngine>js</scriptEngine> 
                </script> 
            </event> 
        </type> 
    </WorkItem> 
</EventTriggerConfiguration>
```

All files of the projects are the same and the `triggers.xml` is located at: .polarion/events. The scripts in the directory scripts. The type id "task" is also defined in Administration/WorkItems/Types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to trigger the script!

You have to first add the Polarion Scripting Engine plugin (search for Polarion PSO SE).
Then edit polarion.properties (/opt/polarion/etc/polarion.properties) and add the following lines:

```
com.polarion.eventhandler.trigger.monitor.enable = true
com.polarion.platform.loggingServiceInterceptor.enabled = false
```

Source for this: https://professionalservices.polarion.com/support/ScriptingEngine/

My local tigger file is as follow:
repo/test/.polarion/events/triggers.xml:

```
 <EventTriggerConfiguration>
    <WorkItem>
        <type id="task">
            <event trigger="pre-save">
                <script>
                    <scriptName>PreTest.js</scriptName>
                    <scriptEngine>javaScript</scriptEngine>
                </script>
            </event>
            <event trigger="post-save">
                <script>
                    <scriptName>PostTest.js</scriptName>
                    <scriptEngine>javaScript</scriptEngine>
                </script>
                <script>
                    <scriptName>PostTest2.js</scriptName>
                    <scriptEngine>javaScript</scriptEngine>
                </script>
            </event>
        </type>
    </WorkItem>
 </EventTriggerConfiguration>
```

After a polarion restart, I now get proper error messages from Polarion UI as well as log. (My script was broken anyways).

Comment: Thank you very much! I wouldn't have thought of adding this 2 lines of code myself. Now it is working well:)